# Writing to memory in .NET and pick up data of process in labview

Tags: c#, marshalling, dispose, memorystream

I am using the Kinect Face-Tracking Basics WPF example to collect data from an object.
I can access the data in a text file etc but I want to write the data to managed memory in a C# process and have labview's .NET program pick up the data from same location.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
                    this.facePoints3D = frame.Get3DShape();

                   // using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                   // {
                        //var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
                        int n = 121;
                        foreach (Vector3DF[] vector in facePoints3D.GetSlices(n))
                        {
                            //convert from float to byte array before we pass on to memory
                            var bytearray = new byte[vector.Length * this.facePoints3D.Count];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(vector, 0, bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);

                           //Initialize unmanaged memory to hold array.
                            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(bytearray[0]) * bytearray.Length;

                            IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

                            try
                            {
                                //copy the array to unmanaged memory.
                                Marshal.Copy(bytearray, 0, pnt, bytearray.Length);

                                // Copy the unmanaged array back to another managed array.

                                byte[] bytearray2 = new byte[bytearray.Length];

                                Marshal.Copy(pnt, bytearray2, 0, bytearray.Length);

                                //Console.WriteLine("The array was coppied to unmanaged memory and back.");
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                // Free the unmanaged memory.
                                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
                            }
```

}

Thus far, I have the labview program configured correctly as

Process A (c#): MemoryStream Buffer -> Marshal AllocHGlobal -> Marshal Copy - > Marshal Dispose -> IntPtr ToInt64
Process B (labview): IntPtr value -> Marshall AllocHGlobal -> Marshal Copy -> Destination

Now the labview end runs well but it doesn't appear to be picking up the values from the Memory location.

Advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those 2 separate processes? (2 separate exes).  If so, you are not going to be able to share memory via direct allocation due to Process Isolation (1 process cannot see another process's memory).

Assuming that your answer is "yes" (2 separate processes), consider using Named Pipes to communicate cross process (or wrap it up with WCF)

Interprocess communication with Named Pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx

WCF Tutorial: basic interprocess communication: http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

You could also use a memory-mapped file: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2012/02/inter-process-communication-using.html

**EDIT**

Added an example of using the binary serializer instead of doing manual memory copies of the structure.  You can write the resulting byte arrays to your memory mapped file.  This solution does require that you apply the [Serializable] attribute to your Vector3DF structure, and it assumes that the code reading the memory has the same type definition for Vector3DF.

(note: in your code in the comments, it looked as though you are working with an array of arrays of Vector3DF structs, so that's how I modeled the serialization code.  Adjust as necessary

```
        public byte[] SerializeVectors(Vector3DF[][] vectors)
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            // note: if you are using a stream to write to the memory mapped file, 
            // you could pass it in instead of using this memory stream as an intermediary
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, vectors);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public Vector3DF[][] DeserializeVectors(byte[] vectorBuffer)
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(vectorBuffer, false))
            {
                return (Vector3DF[][])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
```

Here is a link to a Gist that contains working code and a unit test so that you can play around with it: https://gist.github.com/jsmarsch/d0dcade8c656b94f5c1c

Comment: They are two separate processes, yes @JMarsch. One in C# Writing to Memory Stream and the Other is supposed to pick up the memory location. Thanks for the links. I think the memory-mapped file example will work best for me as of now.

Comment: @Calorified Glad to help.  If this ends up working for you, please mark my response as the answer (checkmark just below the point score).  That will award me some points, but more importantly, it will future readers with the same problem know that this route worked for you.

Comment: hi @JMarsch. I got the mappedmemory file setup but i am having a glitch in my code due to type conversion. Here's the code, maybe you could help out a bit more:                       this.facePoints3D = frame.Get3DShape();
                    foreach (Vector3DF[] vector in facePoints3D.GetSlices(n))
                    {                     
                         byte[] bytearray = new byte[vector.Length * this.facePoints3D.Count];
                         Buffer.BlockCopy(vector, 0, bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                    }

Comment: with vector3df defined as:     public struct Vector3DF
     {
       public Vector3DF(float x, float y, float z)
        : this()
       {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        }
       // ...       
        //some more code
       //...
     }

Comment: I believe that BlockCopy requires an array of primitives (ints, floats, etc), I don't think it will copy an array of struct.  You might have a look at Marshal.StructureToPtr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But also, I think that you are going to run into other issues -- you will have to accurately know the size of the struct, and since you are writing an array of arrays (getslices returns an array of Vector3DF arrays, based on your code), the receiving code is going to have to know the dimensions of both arrays in order to reconstruct everything successfully.  My advice would be to use WCF, perhaps with the binary serializer.  It will handle all of those details for you.  Or, at the very least, use .net serialization to handle wrench work of managing the bits.

Comment: @Calorified I edited my response with an example of using .net serialization to handle the struct to byte array conversion

Comment: Thanks @HMarsch. I will try WCF 'cause the MemoryMapping I've tried all along has not worked. Again, thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this library? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Inter-process-communication-e96e94e7#content  **it's just what I needed.**

Comment: Looks cool!  I would still recommend using Serialization over manual memory manipulation for converting your struct to a byte array and back again.

Comment: **Yes, you, you, you!** I am defo using serialization and it is working fantastic! Also, I am using the MMF library and it's reduced a ton of headache not to mention I got a good samaritan who's got an MMap API in labview that has reduced my workload by a zillion percent. Life is good!

Comment: Hey @JMarsch, I have another question: if I want to compile the C# code as a dll and call the dll within labview's call library function node, I am thinking of the best way to write the Vector[] vector to an output (debug.WriteLine or Console.WriteLine) in order for me to be able to pick up the data in Labview.

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar with LabView, but I can give you some general advice: Based upon this link: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DCB90714981A1F148625731E00797C33  It looks as though LabView has support for working with .Net Assemblies (If you build a Class Library (or an exe, for that matter) in c#, the dll is an assembly in .net terms, which makes it a special DLL.  Since it looks like LabView specifically knows about assemblies (see link above), you might actually find that it imports all of the public types in your assembly as well.

Comment: (continued).  If I'm right about that, you should just be able to call import the assembly, and call your function (returning an array of your Vectors).  (a "normal" .net app is put together like that -- in .net, you can even inherit from a class that is defined in a referenced assembly -- I don't know anything about LabView though.  Is that tool written in .net?

Comment: Yes, I am using the guidance from the link you sent and it seems I have to reengineer the whole code with labview's diagrams. To be safe, I tried UDP earlier and it seems to be working good